# Both windows change when I switch to object mode in second window?

Tags: windows

I'm new to blender and was creating a treasure chest or whatever you call it. I split the blender screen to two windows so that I can see one object in object mode and in second window in rendered mode.But as I change my one window to object mode it changes in both the windows why?

These are the pictures if u don't understand>>>

[image: Here if I change one window to the edit mode the change also occur in second window.]

Comment: Hello :). You're mixing terms a bit. *Edit/Object* modes are in sync for all viewports. But shading (*Solid/Preview/Rendered*) can be different in each viewport.

Comment: So ur saying that if I will change to any mode it will change in both the windows>>>But I was watching a video it was not changing. I don't have any problem with this but it's ok...Thank you!!!

Comment: Correct :). There's currently no way around that. Feel free to link the video, I could be wrong :).

Comment: I'm sending you the video link see his windows:   https://youtu.be/Oko7kas-fu4